# Power BI Simple Bar Chart

Tags: powerbi

I have a simple data set like this where `Column1.day`'s data type is set to text as it represents something in the next 10, 15, 30... days and isn't a number. `Column1.total` is what I want the bar chart to represent.

[image]

I'd like the bar chart to look like this but can't seem to get it to work as the total always is set to count.

10  []

15  []

30  [**]

60  [**]

90  [**]

120  [**]

I can't seem to get this to display like the above, maybe it isn't possible:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data types are important. You should change the data type of `Column1.total` to a number.

Try changing the summary of `Column1.total` in your visualization to `Sum` instead of `Count`

Comment: The column was formatting as if it was a number to the right but after explicitly formatting the column it seems to work correctly.